# input type="date" not firing correct events on some versions of default Android-browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, input

I am developing a website for mobile devices using Angular.js, and have run into an issue with `input type="date"` on *some* default Android-browsers. On affected browsers, values set through the date-control are never bound to the model.

I have narrowed it down to the date picker interfering with the events fired by the input field. This JSBin showcases the issue: http://jsbin.com/riwutijene

(Note that the bound value is updated only on the `blur`-event because Mobile Safari would otherwise cause an update every time a dial is turned before the date picker is dismissed.)

What I expect is for the date selected via the upper date-element to appear below the field after confirming the value. This works as expected on most browser/device-combinations, but not on a very small number of handheld devices, such as an HTC One I use for testing. Unfortunately, the issue can only be reproduced on affected devices.

The problem seems to be a browser-bug that only happens because manufacturers are able to ship the native browser using beta-versions of WebKit. It does not seem to be directly connected to Angular.js, as the events fired by those “faulty” input elements are out of whack regardless (as seen on the bottom date field).

Have any of you run into this issue before, or know of a solid workaround?